# Intersection between context-free and context-sensitive language decidability

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, computability, automata-theory, context-free, decidability

I'm trying to find a formal proof of the following fact:

Given a context-free language, say $L_1$, and a context-sensitive language, say $L_2$, it is NOT decidable if their intersection is empty ($L_1 \cap L_2 = \emptyset$)

Some suggestions for the proof? Thanks

Comment: This seems to be an undergraduate assignment level question and therefore is more suitable for [cs.se].

Comment: This question has been [reposted on Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19326/intersection-between-context-free-and-context-sensitive-language-decidability).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is undecidable even for two context-free languages. See for instance [this page](http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/fcs/other-undecidable.html) for a short proof.

Comment: (It's also undecidable for a single context-sensitive language i.e. $L=\emptyset$)

Comment: Ok, let's suppose that I know that is undecidable for a single context-sensitive language. I want to show that the intersection problem is undecidable too, without using the PCP fact (and directly from CF^CS, not CF^CF). Just a logic or languages proof. How do you do that?

I know it's quite obvious, but I need a rigorous proof  by contradiction, starting from the fact that I know it's undecidable for every c.s. language. 

thank you

Comment: It seems to me this question is an assignment and is therefore off-topic for cstheory.